# CSS - Prevent Background Image from Resizing When Content is Expanded?

Tags: html, css, background-image, expand

I am working on a site that relies heavily on background images and expandable content. However, whenever the content is expanded, the background image resizes as well. This is an expected behavior, but what can I do to prevent it?

Example (https://jsfiddle.net/6a6gwoj4/12/):

`div.content` has height set to `0` until expanded. `div.wrap` has a background image with size set to `cover`. Click read more to expand the content. Because the expanded content exceeds the original height of the wrapper the parent (`div.wrap`) height also changes causing the background image to resize.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">      
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <div class="content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
      <br>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    </div>
    <p class="readmore">
      read more
    </p>      
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.wrap {
  position: relative;
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1515524738708-327f6b0037a7?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&s=cb89fbf71ae49b0a22e3e35e6d856a17&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center;
  padding: 30px;
  color: #fff;
}

div.content {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

div.content.show {
  max-height: 500px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  $('p.readmore').click(function(){
    $('div.content').toggleClass('show');
  });
});
```

Setting a fixed height for `div.wrap` isn't an option, the amount of content varies. Setting the position of `div.content` to `absolute` would stop the parent resizing and fix the issue somewhat. But then this content will overlap on any subesquent elements which makes the UI messy and confusing - user would need to collapse the expanded content again to view the next `div.wrap`.